# expansion of a generating function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I found this formula in a book
$$\sqrt{1-4x}=1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} {{2n-2}\choose {n-1}} x^n$$

How can I prove that?

Comment: That is a Taylor series

Comment: @Dr.MV How can you know that coefficients have that form?

Comment: Do you know how to determine the TS?

Comment: @Dr.MV yes, but if I compute derivatives at $0$, I find: -2, -4, etc. How can I know the general form of the $n$-th coefficient?

Comment: Brian Scott just posted a solution that should be useful. ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to prove it.

You could note that $\frac1n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ is $C_{n-1}$, the $(n-1)$-st Catalan number, so that the formula can be written

$$\sqrt{1-4x}=1-2\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}nx^{n+1}=1-2\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^{n+1}\;.$$

Now you can simply manipulate the [known generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof) for the Catalan numbers:

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1-4x}&=1-2x\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^n\\
&=1-2\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^{n+1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Or you can use the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem):

$$\begin{align*}
(1-4x)^{1/2}&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{1/2}n(-4x)^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n\ge 1}\binom{1/2}n(-1)^n4^nx^n\\
&\overset{*}=1+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}(-1)^n4^nx^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2^{2n}}{2^{2n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}x^n\\
&=1-2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}x^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the starred step is carried out in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340141/12042).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may apply the [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) to $f(x):=\sqrt{1-4x}$,
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n,\quad |x|<\frac14. \tag1
$$
Then one may prove by induction that
$$
\begin{align}
(\sqrt{u})'=& \frac12\cdot u^{1/2-1}
\\(\sqrt{u})^{(2)}=& \frac12\left(\frac12-1 \right)\cdot u^{1/2-2}
\\(\sqrt{u})^{(3)}=& \frac12\left(\frac12-1 \right)\left(\frac12-2 \right)\cdot u^{1/2-3}
\\\cdots =& \cdots
\\(\sqrt{u})^{(n)}=& \frac12\left(\frac12-1 \right)\left(\frac12-2 \right)\cdots \left(\frac12-n+1 \right)\cdot u^{1/2-n}
\end{align}
$$ that is

> $$
> \left.(\sqrt{u})^{(n)}\right|_{u=0}= \frac12\left(\frac12-1 \right)\left(\frac12-2 \right)\cdots \left(\frac12-n+1 \right) \tag2
> $$

From $(2)$ we deduce by the chain rule that, for $n\geq1$,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=&\frac1{n!}\left.(\sqrt{1-4x})^{(n)}\right|_{x=0}
\\\\= &\frac{(-4)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac12\left(\frac12-1 \right)\left(\frac12-2 \right)\cdots \left(\frac12-n+1 \right)
\\\\= &\frac{(-4)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{1\times(-1)\times(-3)\cdots \times(-(2n-3))}{2^n}
\\\\= &2\cdot\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{n-1} 1\times2\times3\cdots \times(2n-3)\times(2n-2)}{1\times2\times3\cdots \times(n-1)}
\\\\= &-\frac2n\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{((n-1)!)^2}
\\\\= &-\frac2n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$ which inserted in $(1)$ gives the announced identity.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. The claim is equivalent to:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n=g(x) \tag{1}$$
but if we set $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ we may check that:
$$ C_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2 (n+2)}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+2} C_n\tag{2}$$
hence it follows that $h(x)=x\cdot g(x)$ is an analytic solution of the differential equation:
$$ (1-4x)\,h'(x)+2\,h(x)=1.\tag{3} $$
However, it is easy to check that $j(x)=x\cdot f(x)$ is an analytic solution of the same differential equation. Since $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(0)=g'(0)$, it follows that $\color{red}{f\equiv g}$ as wanted.