# binomial identity: elementary proof possible?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients

For any $z \in D(0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, the series identity
$$(1-z)^{1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose n} (-z)^n = 1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|{1/2 \choose n}\right|z^n$$ holds. Letting $z \to 1-$ along the real axis, we deduce (aided by the monotone convergence theorem, or an ad hoc argument) that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|{1/2 \choose n}\right| = 1.$$
Can this identity be proven in an elementary (e.g. combinatorial) way?

Comment: The expression for $\binom{1/2}{n}$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340141/137524) seems like it may come in handy.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow the remark about the Monotone Convergence Theorem. I don't suppose you could expand on it a little? I'm sorry if it's something that should be obvious. Faced with the need to prove the same equation, I used Tauber's first theorem: [Convergence of the sum of products $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^k \left(1-\frac{3}{2j}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3817536/213690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ be the $n^{th}$ Catalan number, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 1}\left|\binom{1/2}n\right|
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}(1/2)^{2n-1}\frac1n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}
=\sum_{n\ge 1}(1/2)^{2n-1}C_{n-1}
\end{align}
Note $C_{n-1}$ is the number of simple random walk paths on the real line which stay to the right of the origin. The probability of such a path occurring is $(1/2)^{2n-2}$, because it has $2n-2$ steps. The last factor of $(1/2)$ can be interpreted as the probability of an additional left step. Therefore, the summand $(1/2)^{2n-1}C_{n-1}$ is the probability that the random walk hits $-1$ for the first time after $2n-1$ steps. Since such a random walk hits $-1$ eventually with probability one, these probabilities sum to one.