# Taylor series expansion of $(1+x)^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, formal-power-series

I'm trying to find the formal Taylor series expansion of (1+x)<sup>1/n</sup> but I keep getting stuck. I tried the binomial expansion and while I managed it, I can't quite figure out how to change it to a general summation formula.

I tried the derivative method too but it got a bit complicated for me. Is there a shortcut for this. Maybe another Taylor series I can manipulate?

Thanks

Comment: You need it in $0$?

Comment: Yes I  need the series around 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial series is given as:

$$ (1+x)^j = 1 + jx + j(j-1) \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$$

Sub $j = \frac{1}{n}$

$$ ( 1+x)^{\frac{1}{n} }  = 1 + \frac{x}{n} + \frac{1}{n} ( \frac{1}{n} -1) \frac{x^2}{2}...$$

---

To write as sum you must use the falling factorial defined as follows:

$$ r^{ \underline{k} } = r (r-1)(r-2)..(r-k+1)$$

Examples:

$$ k = 0$$

$$ r^{ \underline{0} } = 1$$

$$ k=2$$

$$ r^{ \underline{2} } = r(r-1)$$

Hence, the binomial series is:

$$ (1+x)^{\frac{1}{n} }  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n})^{ \underline{k} }  
 \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: This I got. I got confused trying to make a general summation formula for this as the powers of x are changing but the denominator 'n' is not so if I make a series that sums over n, it gets weird.

Comment: I have made an edit

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the falling factorial notation.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just use $$\left((1+x)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{(k)}_{x=0}=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right)...\left(\frac{1}{n}-k+1\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

By the [Binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we have $$(1+x)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n\choose k}x^{k}$$

since we know that $${n\choose k}=\begin{cases} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\space\text{for $0\leq k \leq n$}\\\space\space\space\space0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Thus we have $$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\choose r}x^{r}.$$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340124/binomial-coefficients-1-2-choose-k). Indeed  $$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\choose r}x^{r}={\frac{1}{n}\choose 0}+{\frac{1}{n}\choose 1}x+{\frac{1}{n}\choose 2}x^{2}+...$$
$$=1+\frac{x}{n}+\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}-1)\frac{x^2}{2}+...$$