Help troubleshooting ellipse perimeter calculation algorithm
I'm trying to troubleshoot my implementation of an Infinite Series algorithm to calculate the perimeter of an ellipse.  I'm sorry I don't have the expertise to express it in, what appears to be a specialized language this site uses to make it more readable but I'm confident you'll recognize what I'm trying to do.
h =  (a − b)^2/(a + b)^2
pi(a+b) (1 + (1/4)h + (1/64)h^2 + (1/256)h^3 + ...)

The site I got this formula from has a calculator but it doesn't show it's work.  My results don't match it's results but I don't see where I'm going wrong.  I've left out the final multiplication by pi since the error is clearly prior to that point.  It's result 40.63874136 after division by pi = 12.93571313 which is quite far from my 14.9879.
Honestly, I don't need someone to understand the language and fix my algorithm.  This language is esoteric.  A comment along the lines of "your h value should be..." or "Your B,C and HI values look OK but your P values should read: nnn1,nnn2,nnn3" should help me find and fix the problem.
function EllipseEffectiveDiameter(rx=10,ry=1,i=5) =
    assert(rx>=0)
    assert(ry>=0)
    assert(i%1==0&&i>=1)
    let(d = rx-ry ,
        s = rx+ry ,
        h = d^2/s^2,
        m = _InfiniteSum(h=h,i=i,s=0),
        a = s*m)                                    echo(d=d,s=s,h=h,m=m,a=a)
    a;

//ECHO: d = 9, s = 11, h = 0.669421, m = 1.36254, a = 14.9879
 
function _InfiniteSumPart(h,i,s) =
    let(B = BinomialCoefficient(m=1/2,k=i),
        C = B^2,
        HI= h^i,
        P = C*HI,
        A = s+P)                                    echo(h=h,i=i,s=s,B=B,C=C,HI=HI,P=P,A=A)
    i==0?A:A+_InfiniteSumPart(h,i=i-1,s=A);

//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 5, s = 0          , B = 0.0273438 , C = 0.000747681, HI = 0.134431, P = 0.000100511, A = 0.000100511
//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 4, s = 0.000100511, B = -0.0390625, C = 0.00152588 , HI = 0.200816, P = 0.000306421, A = 0.000406932
//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 3, s = 0.000406932, B = 0.0625    , C = 0.00390625 , HI = 0.299985, P = 0.00117181 , A = 0.00157875
//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 2, s = 0.00157875 , B = -0.125    , C = 0.015625   , HI = 0.448125, P = 0.00700196 , A = 0.0085807
//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 1, s = 0.0085807  , B = 0.5       , C = 0.25       , HI = 0.669421, P = 0.167355   , A = 0.175936
//ECHO: h = 0.669421, i = 0, s = 0.175936   , B = 1         , C = 1          , HI = 1       , P = 1          , A = 1.17594
 

Note: I'm only including this for completeness.  Several sites use my exact values as examples where their work is shown so I'm fairly confident the problem isn't down here. It's results are column B above.
function BinomialCoefficient(m=1/2,k=1) = 
    assert(k%1==0 && k>=0)
    k==0?1:_BinomialCoefficient(m=m,k=k,i=0,PM=1,PK=1);
 
function _BinomialCoefficient(m,k,i,PM,PK) =
    let(IM = m-i,
        IK = i+1,
        NM = PM*IM,
        NK = PK*IK,
        A  = NM/NK)                                   //echo(m=m,k=k,i=i,PM=PM,PK=PK,IM=IM,IK=IK,NM=NM,NK=NK,A=A)
    k==1?A:_BinomialCoefficient(m=m,k=k-1,i=IK,PM=NM,PK=NK);

UPDATE:
It might be that reading the language is only straightforward if you are accustomed to declarative languages.  The most starkly un-nerving thing about declaratives is that variable values can't change. Therefore loops are often done with recursion which I use in both _InfiniteSumPart and _BinomialCoefficient.
The operators allowed in a value or result formula are the basic ones typical of languages like C.  If decisions are required, the "bool?true:false" syntax is available and I use this to decide when to recurs or stop.
When it comes to the infinite sum part, being sums, I didn't think it really mattered in what order I computed the terms so I counted down rather than counting up.  This should amount (if $i=2$ were used) to ${1h^2}/64 + 1h/4 + 1$ rather than $1 + 1h/4 + 1h^2/64$. Although this could make the running (P)roduct and (A)nswer columns differ from initial expectations, hopefully it isn't directly causing the problem.

It's not easy to spot how you computed the coefficients of the series: could you explain in more detail?

Do you mean the Binomial Coefficient  routine?  I tried to implement this formula https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340138 .   My results matched the example half way down this page https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html which happen to be exactly the values I need here so I assume they are correct.  Search for "the next term is" on that page for the values I used as validation and appear here in column C.  If you are referring to some other part I'll update the question to clarify once I understand.  The language itself is declarative and hard to explain but I'll try.

If I take your last result $A=1.17594$ and multiply it by $s=11$ I get the right result $12.936$.

Yikes, yes.  How did I miss that.  Thanks

If you aren't able to figure it out and it's a problem with the code and formula you may want to try one of these instead; they are highly accurate, with maximum errors of .04%, .015% and .02%:

